# Empty value from web scraping with python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrap this website but having issues extracting the right values. The website is on the prices of Sliver, gold, palladium and platinum. http://www.lbma.org.uk/precious-metal-prices 
The html of the website is below.

```
      <div id="header-tabs-content" data-tabs-content="header-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="header-tabs-panel1" 
     role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="header-tabs-
     panel1-label">
          <a href="/precious-metal-prices">
          <p>Gold Price</p>
          <p>AM: 
              <strong>$
              <span id="daily_gold_am_usd">1325.40</span>
              </strong> <br>
            <em class="update">Updated: <span 
          id="daily_gold_am_timestamp">08/03 10:31:00</span></em> </p>
          <p>PM: 
              <strong>$
              <span id="daily_gold_pm_usd">1321.00</span>
              </strong> <br>
            <em class="update">Updated: <span 
          id="daily_gold_pm_timestamp">08/03 15:02:00</span></em> </p>
            </a>
```

I am interested to obtain the daily_gold_am_usd of 1325.40 and the daily_gold_pm_usd of 1321.00 from the html data structure below. However the code I attempted after consulting from past posts can't seems to return these values.

```
#Import packages

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#define url and get html

url = "http://www.lbma.org.uk/precious-metal-prices"
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

#Find the object of interest

gold_am_price = soup.find("span", {"id": "daily_gold_am_usd"})
Au_price_am = gold_am_price.text.strip()

gold_pm_price = soup.find("span", {"id": "daily_gold_pm_usd"})
Au_price_pm = gold_pm_price.text.strip()
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks guys.

Comment: I've checked the html source of the page and the site does not seem to have the prices at the moment. Maybe that's why the variables are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values comes from XHR to http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/api/today/both.json, so you can get them as:

```
import requests
url = "http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/api/today/both.json"
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

Output of `print(response)`:

```
{'gold': {'am': {'usd': '1325.40', 'gbp': '955.080', 'eur': '1070.390', 'timesta
mp': '08/03 10:31:00'}, 'pm': {'usd': '1321.00', 'gbp': '953.370', 'eur': '1069.
750', 'timestamp': '08/03 15:02:00'}}, 'silver': {'usd': '16.48000', 'usdc': '16
48', 'gbp': '11.89000', 'gbpp': '1189', 'eur': '13.31000', 'eurc': '1331', 'time
stamp': '08/03 12:01:00'}, 'platinum': {'am': {'usd': '949.00', 'gbp': '683.960'
, 'eur': '766.250', 'timestamp': '08/03 09:49:00'}, 'pm': {'usd': '954.00', 'gbp
': '687.570', 'eur': '769.670', 'timestamp': '08/03 14:09:00'}}, 'palladium': {'
am': {'usd': '970.00', 'gbp': '699.100', 'eur': '783.210', 'timestamp': '08/03 0
9:49:00'}, 'pm': {'usd': '985.00', 'gbp': '709.910', 'eur': '794.680', 'timestam
p': '08/03 14:09:00'}}}
```

Then you can extract required as:

```
response['gold']['am']['usd']  #  1325.40
response['gold']['pm']['usd']  #  1321.00
```

Comment: works like a charm! Much appreciated. I was wondering how did you get the address for "http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/api/today/both.json" ? I could only see "http://lbma.oblive.co.uk" or "http://lbma.oblive.co.uk/table" in the view source.

Comment: Press F12 -> Switch to Network tab -> Enable XHR sub-tab only -> open http://www.lbma.org.uk/precious-metal-prices -> Check URL of sent XHR